grafana table to show counter division aggregation values in selected time range
I'm new to prometheus and grafana and stuck with such query and dashboard.
In prometheus there are 2 counters with shared labels. for example:
upload_file_size_total{filetype="jpg", version="v1"} 263.0
upload_file_count_total{filetype="png", version="v2"} 2.0

Following I'll create shorter names:

upload_file_size_total: s
upload_file_count_total: c
filetype: t
version: v

now want a grafana dashboard to show min, ave, max of s/c during selected time range.
Some design decisions:

why 2 counters and not single gauge? Because I worry important data not taken into account due to scraping interval is at least 15s.
why not use histogram or summary? Because I want as accurate min, max as possible, since this is also easier to test. as far as I know,
histogram or summary doesn't provide min, max directly and are estimated.

I have tried a Time Series and Bar Gauge with following query:
sum(increase(f[$__range])) by (t,v)
/sum(increase(c[$__range])) by (t,v)

and works just fine, except only average value and missing min, max.
Then I tried Table with query
sum(increase(f)) by (t,v)
/sum(increase(c)) by (t,v)

But it displays time, f, v, value as columns, not expected.
Then tried adding a transformation converting series to rows, and selecting min, mean, max aggregations.
The table columns are f, a, min, mean, max, as expected, but data are calculated from the beginning and not the selected range.
If add $__range
sum(increase(f)[$__range]) by (t,v)
/sum(increase(c)[$__range]) by (t,v)

I got null for almost all values. but not know why.
I even tried some query like
min
(
    sum(increase(f[$__range])) by (t,v)
    /
    sum(increase(c[$__range])) by (t,v)
)by(t,v),
mean
(
    sum(increase(f[$__range])) by (t,v)
    /
    sum(increase(c[$__range])) by (t,v)
)by(t,v),
max
(
    sum(increase(f[$__range])) by (t,v)
    /
    sum(increase(c[$__range])) by (t,v)
)by(t,v)

but seems syntax is wrong.
Could anyone suggest? many thanks! I'm using Grafana v11.1.4.
